# How can I format tqdm progress bar to show progress per minute instead of per second?

Tags: python, python-3.x, progress-bar, tqdm

I couldn't find this on [GitHub](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) or in the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/) but I'm wondering whether there is an integrated way (preferred) or workaround to show the average time it takes for one iteration in minutes rather than seconds.

Specifically, tqdm shows something like `1283.31s/it` but if each iteration takes several minutes or hours, it would be more helpful to show something like `21m/it`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by adding a custom `bar_format` parameter to a custom instance of `tqdm` using the instructions [partially described in the manual](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#description-and-additional-stats):

```
class TqdmExtraFormat(tqdm):
    """Provides a `minutes per iteration` format parameter"""
    @property
    def format_dict(self):
        d = super(TqdmExtraFormat, self).format_dict
        rate_min = '{:.2f}'.format(1/d["rate"] / 60) if d["rate"] else '?'
        d.update(rate_min=(rate_min + ' min/' + d['unit']))
        return d
```

What we're doing here is overriding `format_dict` with a custom version that adds a new stat that can be used in the `bar_format` argument. `d` is the existing `format_dict`, so we can use that to get the value of `{rate}`, convert it to time per iteration (1/rate), divide by 60, then format it to 2 decimal places. Then, we update `d` with the new stat – we can even use string concatenation to add some formatting. Note that before any iterations have completed, `{rate}` is `None`, which means that this will give an error unless you do the `if d["rate"]` check.

Once this is done, we can use this stat in the `bar_format` parameter string alongside the ones listed in [Parameters](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#parameters) if you use your custom instance of `tqdm`:

```
b='{l_bar}{bar}| {n_fmt}/{total_fmt} [{elapsed}<{remaining}, {rate_min}{postfix}]'
for i in TqdmExtraFormat(range(2), unit_scale = 60, bar_format=b):
    time.sleep(6)
```

[image]

Comment: class TqdmExtraFormat(tqdm):
TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)